# How to scrape elements in Selenium/Python by calling different css selectors at the same time?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am trying to select the title of posts that are loaded in a webpage by integrating multiple css selectors. See below my process:

Load relevant libraries

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Then load the content I wish to analyse

```
options = Options()
options.set_preference("dom.push.enabled", False)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

browser.get("https://medium.com/search")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']").send_keys("international development",Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)

scrolls = 2
while True:
    scrolls -= 1
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(5)
    if scrolls < 0:
        break
```

Then to get the content for each selector separately, call for css_selector

```
titles=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("h3[class^='graf']")
TitlesList = []
for names in titles:
    names.text
    TitlesList.append(names.text) 

times=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("time[datetime^='2016']")
Times = []
for names in times:
    names.text
    Times.append(names.text)
```

It all works so far...Now trying to bring them together with the aim to identify only choices from 2016

```
choices = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("time[datetime^='2016'] and h3[class^='graf']")    
browser.quit()
```

On this last snippet, I always get an empty list.

So I wonder 1) How can I select multiple elements by considering different css_selector as conditions for selection at the same time 2) if the syntax to find under multiple conditions would be the same to link elements by using different approaches like css_selector or x_paths and 3) if there is a way to get the text for elements identified by calling for multiple css selectors along a similar line of what below:

```
[pair.text for pair in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("h3[class^='graf']") if pair.text]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I think what you're trying to do is to get any title that has time posted in 2016 right?

You're using CSS selector `"time[datetime^='2016'] and h3[class^='graf']"`, but this will not work because its syntax is not valid (`and` is not valid). Plus, these are 2 different elements, CSS selector can only find 1 element. In your case, to add a condition from another element, use a common element like a parent element or something.

I've checked the site, here's the HTML that you need to take a look at (if you're trying to the title that published in 2016). This is the minimal HTML part that can help you identify what you need to get.

```html
<div class="postArticle postArticle--short js-postArticle js-trackPostPresentation" data-post-id="d17220aecaa8"
    data-source="search_post---------2">
    <div class="u-clearfix u-marginBottom15 u-paddingTop5">
        <div class="postMetaInline u-floatLeft u-sm-maxWidthFullWidth">
            <div class="u-flexCenter">
                <div class="postMetaInline postMetaInline-authorLockup ui-captionStrong u-flex1 u-noWrapWithEllipsis">
                    <div
                        class="ui-caption u-fontSize12 u-baseColor--textNormal u-textColorNormal js-postMetaInlineSupplemental">
                        <a class="link link--darken"
                            href="https://provocations.darkmatterlabs.org/reimagining-international-development-for-the-21st-century-d17220aecaa8?source=search_post---------2"
                            data-action="open-post"
                            data-action-value="https://provocations.darkmatterlabs.org/reimagining-international-development-for-the-21st-century-d17220aecaa8?source=search_post---------2"
                            data-action-source="preview-listing">
                            <time datetime="2016-09-05T13:55:05.811Z">Sep 5, 2016</time>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="postArticle-content">
        <a href="https://provocations.darkmatterlabs.org/reimagining-international-development-for-the-21st-century-d17220aecaa8?source=search_post---------2"
            data-action="open-post" data-action-source="search_post---------2"
            data-action-value="https://provocations.darkmatterlabs.org/reimagining-international-development-for-the-21st-century-d17220aecaa8?source=search_post---------2"
            data-action-index="2" data-post-id="d17220aecaa8">
            <section class="section section--body section--first section--last">
                <div class="section-divider">
                    <hr class="section-divider">
                </div>
                <div class="section-content">
                    <div class="section-inner sectionLayout--insetColumn">
                        <h3 name="5910" id="5910" class="graf graf--h3 graf--leading graf--title">Reimagining
                            International Development for the 21st&nbsp;Century.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Both `time` and `h3` are in a big `div` with class of `postArticle`. The article contains time published & the title, so it makes sense to get the whole article `div` that published in 2016 right?

Using XPATH is much more powerful & easier to write:

- This will get all articles `div` that contains class name of `postArticle--short`: `article_xpath = '//div[contains(@class, "postArticle--short")]'`
- This will get all `time` tag that contains class name of `2016`: `//time[contains(@datetime, "2016")]`

Let's combine both of them. I want to get article `div` that contains a `time` tag with classname of `2016`:

```py
article_2016_xpath = '//div[contains(@class, "postArticle--short")][.//time[contains(@datetime, "2016")]]'
article_element_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(article_2016_xpath)

# now let's get the title
for article in article_element_list:
    title = article.find_element_by_tag_name("h3").text
```

I haven't tested the code yet, only the xpath. You might need to adapt the code to work on your side.

---

By the way, using `find_element...` is not a good idea, try using explicit wait: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

This will help you to avoid making stupid `time.sleep` waits and improve your app performance, and you can handle errors pretty well.

Only use `find_element...` when you already located the element, and you need to find a child element inside. For example, in this case if I want to find articles, I will find by explicit wait, then after the element is located, I will use `find_element...` to find child element `h3`.

Comment: This is a fine input. I was specifically looking at css structure to call the subset of articles from 2016, I wish to know if there is an equivalent way. You have done it with xpath and by just appending the result to a list the data is scraped. I was testing away different syntax and combo of iterations with css though. I am stuck in formulating something along this line: `article_2016_css="div[class*='postArticle--short']>time[datetime*='2016']"`
`article_element_list_css = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(article_2016_css)` but still get an empty list..

Comment: From what I know, there's no way to crawl this type of HTML structure via CSS efficiently. You can use CSS selector `div[class*='postArticle--short']>div>div>div>div>div>a>time[datetime^="2016"]` to get the right post that you need, but this will return a `time` tag, which you have to get the article content with extra steps (getting parent of parent of parent element... then get the `h3` child). It's doable, but I don't think it's a good way to do. CSS selector is very limited. Using XPATH is a bit slower but easier to make the right condition to get what you need.

Comment: I agree with your argument but just to fully understand the logic and limitation of css selectors. If I use the selector you shared, I get a list of items but then to get the article title I cannot use `article.find_element_by_tag_name("h3").text` instead I am trying to call the full path `for article in article_element_list_css:
    titles = article.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class*='postArticle--short']>div>a>section>div>div>h3[class*='graf']") ` but even then I do not get a matching list between articles and year tags like with the XPATH.

Comment: You can't do that with CSS selector (for now). Check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has. No browser supports it.